# Новый объект рисуется поверх, не стирая предыдущего

Tags: java

Я хочу чтобы кольцо двигалось по экрану и чтобы оно было только одно на экране. Но получается так, что старые кольца остаются в виде "следа". Как я понял repaint() должен стирать старое и рисовать новое, но этого почему то не происходит. Почему я так решил? Я видел, что другие делают также, и у них все работает. Помогите решить эту проблему, может я делаю что-то не так.
Вот код:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JustGame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.add(new Testy());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Testy extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    Image img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\User\\IdeaProjects\\Game\\src\\ring.png").getImage();

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int speed = 2;

    Timer timer = new Timer(20, this);

    public Testy() {
        timer.start();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, x, y,100, 100, null);
    }

    void move() {
        x += speed;
        y += speed;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
        move();
    }
}
```

Comment: Метод paint() в Swing является частью внутренней системы и выполняет важную работу. Переопределять его для рисования компонента Swing не следует.

Comment: Тут ответ есть переписывать неохота https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432816/how-to-move-an-image-animation

Comment: @coder675 я поменял "paint" на "paintComponent" и добавил "super.paintComponent(g);" и у меня все получилось. Только теперь вопрос: теперь это правильно с точки зрения "правильности кода"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте `super.paint(g);` в начало метода `paint`.