# В противоположной стороне экрана появляется дубликат кнопки

Tags: java, swing

Обучаюсь работе с графическими интерфейсами. Не пойму почему при добавлении в например SOUTH часть фрейма моей кнопки при запуске приложения сверху есть её графический дубликат. Эксперементировал и если добавляю в EAST то дубликат будет в WEST. 
При чем развернув в фулл скин окно дубликат пропадает и больше не появляется при этом запуске.

Хочется понять из за чего именно это происходит.

Вот что получается при запуске:

[image: При запуске]

Вот после фулл скрина:

[image: После фулл скрина]

Код программы:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SimpleAnimation {

    int x = 70;
    int y = 70;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleAnimation gui = new SimpleAnimation();
        gui.go();    
    }

    public void go() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame(); 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton button = new JButton("Button");

        MyDrawPanel drawPanel = new MyDrawPanel();

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,drawPanel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,button);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        for(int i = 0; i < 130; i++) {    
            x++;
            y++;

            drawPanel.repaint();

            try {    
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (Exception ex) {}
        }
    }

    class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillOval(x,y,100,100);
        }    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Потому, что надо начать изучать потоки.

Comment: @RomanC потоки?

Comment: Threads @default

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте `super.paintComponent`:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
```

Из документации [`JComponent.paintComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics)):

> ... Further, if you do not invoker super's implementation you must honor the opaque property, that is if this component is opaque, you must completely fill in the background in a non-opaque color. If you do not honor the opaque property you will likely see visual artifacts.

Вкратце, тут говорится что если не вызывается реализация предка (`super`), то компонент нужно вручную закрашивать прозрачным цветом.

У нас уже был похожий вопрос ([Новый объект рисуется поверх, не стирая предыдущего](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/991812/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE)), но есть небольшое отличие, т.ч. не стал отмечать как дубликат.

Comment: Исправило артефакт да еще и анимация стала работать так как задумано, спасибо.